# String was not recognized as a valid DateTime(System.FormatException)?

Tags: c#

I am getting error as:

> An exception of type 'System.FormatException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
>   but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.

This is my code :

```
if (txtRefDate.Text != "")
{
    string[] splitdate = txtRefDate.Text.Split('-');
    string newdate = splitdate[1] + "-" + splitdate[0] + "-" + splitdate[2];
    DateTime Compdate = Convert.ToDateTime(newdate);//On this line i'm getting error
    string date = Compdate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
    obj.RefrenceDate = Convert.ToDateTime(date);
}
```

I am using `CalenderExtender` on my `textbox`. I tried `Parse` and `ParseExact`, but it is not working.
What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Please show us some examples of `txtRefDate.Text` that are not working

Comment: Why are you converting to a DateTime, writing out to a string, then converting again?

Comment: @john I didn't got your point.

Comment: @john endianess has nothing to do with dates. Date formats aren't related to machines either. They differ by *culture*. In a web site, every request may use a different culture based on the *browser* settings

Comment: Actually, I suspect ASP.Net Webforms here, because of the CalendarExtender mention. But the nice thing about the CalendarExtender control is it should provide him a known format for the date string, regardless of the browser culture.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
DateTime Compdate;
if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtRefDate.Text) && DateTime.TryParse(txtRefDate.Text, out Compdate))
{
    obj.RefrenceDate = Compdate.Date;
}
```

Also take a look at `TryParseExact()`, which allows you to supply more info about the expected format of your input.

And if this fails, start logging the string values that fail. We need to see examples of what didn't work.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But when I'm doing this I get exception as `An exception of type 'System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlTypeException' occurred in System.Data.dll but was not handled in user code` with addition information as `SqlDateTime overflow. Must be between 1/1/1753 12:00:00 AM and 12/31/9999 11:59:59 PM.`

Comment: @Dungeon "My code was earlier working fine without any problem" then why did you ask the question?

Comment: @Dungeon Seriously though. Have you verified the date strings you're using represent legal SqlDateTime values? Regardless, that sounds like a different question.

Answer (score 2):

Hmm you seem to be doing a lot of unnecessary steps to parse and set a `DateTime`

```
var textDate = "06-20-2018";

if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(textDate))
{
    var parsedDate = DateTime.ParseExact(textDate, "MM-dd-yyyy", null);

    obj.RefrenceDate = parsedDate;
}
```